# UINavigationController pop animation behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Trying to set the navigation bar background to transparent right **before** the pop animation runs. But it ends up bleeding into the pop transition animation. Is this a bug? I've tried things like `setNeedsDisplay` and `setNeedsLayout`.

```
@IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

If I comment out `popViewController(_:)` the navigation bar changes as expected.

Any help welcome.

**EDIT**

If I wrap the pop call in the completion of a zero duration animation it works. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, animations: {}) { (_) in
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: It's definitely not a bug; you're calling these tasks together and they're executing together. The `animate()` method has now in effect separated them. Have you tried a completion block?

Comment: I just found it strange that it would implicitly add the execution into the animation. Even when I put the code in `viewWillDisappear(_:)`.